# System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Invalid File type, Please upload csv file., Actual :Script-thrown exception

Tags: apex, code-coverage, apextestrunresult

**Test class**

```java
@isTest
public class Participants2Test {
    @testSetup
    private static void testSetup(){
        TestUtility.setup();
    }
    @isTest
    static void testCsvFileRead() {
        // Create test data for the CSV file
        String csvFile = 'Name,Phone,Email,Street,City,State,Country,Zip\nJohn,555-555-5555,john@example.com,123 Main St,Anycity,Anystate,USA,11111\nJane,555-555-5555,jane@example.com,123 Main St,Anycity,Anystate,USA,11111';
        
        // Insert the ContentVersion and ContentDocument records
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.Title = 'Test CSV File';
        cv.PathOnClient = 'TestCSVFile.csv';
        cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(csvFile);
       
        insert cv;
        
        opportunity o=new opportunity();
        o.name='test';
        o.StageName='prospecting';
        o.CloseDate=system.today();
        insert o;
        
        Workshop__c w=new Workshop__c();
        w.Name='testing';
        w.Opportunity__c=o.id;
        insert w;
        
        //Create a new participant
        
        Participant__c participant = new Participant__c();
        participant.Name               = 'Test1';
        participant.Workshop__c        = w.id;
        participant.Phone__c           = '7680011137';
        participant.Email_ID__c        = 'test@gmail.com';
        participant.Street__c          = 'Image gardens';
        participant.City__c            = 'Madhapur';
        participant.Country__c         = 'India';
        participant.State__c           = 'Telangana';
        // participant.Zip_Postal_code__c = '789,632';
        insert participant;
        
        //Query the contentDocumentId
        
         ContentVersion insertedFile = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:cv.Id]; 
        
            //ContentDocument cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title = 'Test CSV File'];
            
        
        //Link the file with the participant
        ContentDocumentLink linkedFile = new ContentDocumentLink(LinkedEntityId=participant.Id, ContentDocumentId=insertedFile.ContentDocumentId);
        insert linkedFile;
    


        

        try {
            Participants2.csvFileRead(cv.ContentDocumentId, w.Id);
            System.assert(false, 'Expected exception was not thrown');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.assertEquals('Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.', e.getMessage());
        }

       
        // Setup the data needed to run the test
        // ...
        
        try {
            // Call the method to test with valid data
            List<Participant__c> participantList = Participants2.csvFileRead(cv.ContentDocumentId, 'Workshop 1');
            // Assert the results
            System.assertEquals(2, participantList.size(), 'Unexpected number of participants');
            System.assertEquals('Participant 1', participantList[0].Name, 'Unexpected name of first participant');
            // Continue with more assertions as needed
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // If an unexpected exception is thrown, the test will fail
            System.assert(true, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Apex class**

```java
public with sharing class Participants2 {
    @AuraEnabled   
    public static list<Participant__c> csvFileRead(Id contentDocumentId,string Workshopid){
        
        system.debug('-Workshopid-'+Workshopid);
       
        if (contentDocumentId == null) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.');
        }
        
        // Initialize an empty list of Participant__c objects
        list<Participant__c> participantInsertList = new list<Participant__c>();
        
        // Check if the contentDocumentId passed to the method is not null
        if(contentDocumentId != null) {
            system.debug('1'+contentDocumentId);
            
            // Fetch File Data based on the basic of document id 
            // Fetch the ContentVersion object associated with the passed contentDocumentId
            
             ContentVersion contentVersionObj = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId =:contentDocumentId];
            system.debug('2'+contentVersionObj);
            
            // Split the VersionData (CSV file data) into a list of strings, where each string is a row in the CSV
            
            list<String> csvRecordsList = contentVersionObj.VersionData.toString().split('\n');

            // Iterate through each row in the CSV file
            for(Integer i = 1; i < csvRecordsList.size(); i++){
                
                 // Create a new Participant__c object for each row
                 
                Participant__c participantObj = new Participant__c();
                
                // Split the current row into a list of strings, where each string is a column in the row
               
                list<String> csvRowData = csvRecordsList[i].split(',');
                System.debug('csvRowData====> '+csvRowData);
                // Assign the values from the CSV file to the fields of the Participant__c object
                
                participantObj.Name = csvRowData[0]; 
                participantObj.Workshop__c = Workshopid;
                participantObj.Phone__c=csvRowData[1];
                participantObj.Email_ID__c=csvRowData[2];
                participantObj.Street__c=csvRowData[3];
                participantObj.City__c=csvRowData[4];
                participantObj.State__c=csvRowData[5];
                participantObj.Country__c=csvRowData[6];
                participantObj.Zip_Postal_code__c=csvRowData[7];
                
                // Add the newly created and populated Participant__c object to the participantInsertList
                participantInsertList.add(participantObj);
            }

            try{  
                // Insert all the Participant__c objects in the participantInsertList into the database
                
                if(!participantInsertList.isEmpty()) {
                    insert participantInsertList;
                }
            }
           catch (Exception ex) {
               
               // If there is an exception, throw a new AuraHandledException with the error message
                throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
            } 
        } /*else {
                throw new AuraHandledException('Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.');
            } */
        return participantInsertList;    
    }

}
```

Error is:

> Class.Participants2Test.testCsvFileRead: line 64, column 1
> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Invalid File type, Please upload csv file., Actual: Script-thrown exception

Answer (score 0):

You should explicit set the message of your exception calling `setMessage()`, just passing it to the constructor is not enough:

```java
if (contentDocumentId == null) {
    AuraHandledException ex = new AuraHandledException('Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.');
    ex.setMessage('Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.');
    throw ex;
}
```

I would also suggest to store this message in a Custom Label, so you don't have to change the code if you want to change it. Even a constant, referenced both in the main class and in the test method, would be an improvement, i.e.:

```java
public with sharing class Participants2 {
    public static final String INVALID_FILE_TYPE_MESSAGE = 'Invalid File type, Please upload csv file.';

    @AuraEnabled   
    public static list<Participant__c> csvFileRead(Id contentDocumentId,string Workshopid){
        // original code
        if (contentDocumentId == null) {
            AuraHandledException ex = new AuraHandledException(INVALID_FILE_TYPE_MESSAGE);
            ex.setMessage(INVALID_FILE_TYPE_MESSAGE);
            throw ex;
        }

        // other code
    }
}
```

Test class

```java
System.assertEquals(Participants2.INVALID_FILE_TYPE_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
```

Comment: thank you RubenDG sir,  I'm adding above code lines but I'm getting error is -- Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts

Comment: @YETURUCHENCHU Probably there is a trigger on the created object (Opportunity, Workshop__c, Participant__c) that calls an async process (future method, queueable, etc...) to execute a callout. In this case you should [set the appropriate mock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) in your test method.

Comment: I wrote a Call the method --- 

// Set up the mock callout
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv');
        response.setBody(csvFile);
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        HttpCalloutMock mock = new HttpCalloutMock();
        mock.responder = (HttpRequest req) -> {
            return response;
        };
        
        Test.startTest();
        HttpCalloutMock.setStub(mock);

but its not working -- 
error is --- 
Type cannot be constructed: System.HttpCalloutMock

Comment: @YETURUCHENCHU It cannot be constructed because it's an interface. Please review the documentation linked in the previous comment, it has a good example. If you still get errors please update the question adding the code of the mock.